# Weechat add hook command in every send Messages

Tags: irc, weechat

I am a new user in Weechat. I have made a customized weechat script from another existing script. To run that script I need to use hook command every time i send text to channel . For example `/myhook  message_to_channel` . I want to automate this process so every time I send messages to a channel i wouldn't need to write `/myhook` but just `message_to_channel` . Is there any way I  could make it happen. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `alias` plugin that is included in WeeChat by default can facilitate this.

You can run the following command to create the alias you want.

```
/alias add message_to_channel /myhook message_to_channel
```

After that, you should be able to just use `/message_to_channel`. You can also add arguments if you like:

> ```
>     $n: argument 'n' (between 1 and 9)
>    $-m: arguments from 1 to 'm'
>    $n-: arguments from 'n' to last
>   $n-m: arguments from 'n' to 'm'
>     $*: all arguments
>     $~: last argument
>   $var: where "var" is a local variable of buffer (see /buffer localvar)
>         examples: $nick, $channel, $server, $plugin, $name
> ```

The documentation is [here](https://weechat.org/files/doc/stable/weechat_user.en.html#alias_plugin).